# firewire device 'rediscovered' every few seconds

Tags: syslog, firewire

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 (again) today and I find that syslog is positively FILLED with messages like this:

```
Mar 29 22:17:08 vpn kernel: [ 2172.084466] firewire_core 0000:05:02.0: rediscovered device fw0
```

They are sometimes as frequent as every second.  My computer *does* have a firewire port, but I don't own any firewire devices and have never used it.  I assume the installer discovered it and I would like to know how to shut it up about the thing.  I tried searching for info about the message and found lots of questions about getting cameras working.  Google doesn't believe I'm searching for **firewire** and even when I click the link to assure it that is what I meant, almost all matches are about fire**WALL**s instead.  I'm hoping a kind soul will be able to let me know the magic command I need to shut this this off and have it never auto-detected/enabled again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't own any firewire devices, you can blacklist the kernel module:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and then you add this line:

```
blacklist firewire-core
```

It's a good idea to recreate the *initramfs* and then reboot:

```
sudo update-initramfs -k all -u && sudo reboot
```

Comment: I also blacklisted firewire-ohci ... I don't know what it did, but if it was firewire related, I didn't need it, I hope.  Anyway, the system seems to be working and not logging any firewire messages, so THANKS!